# What is the Apache equivalent of cPanel "Addon Domains"?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost

I've previously used cPanel, which has a feature called [Add on Domains](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Addon+Domain), that allows a web domain to point to a subfolder on the `public_html`.

I have switched to a Linux server that does not have cPanel on it, and would like to do the same thing in Apache.

How would I do this?

Comment: In Apache, that's called a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Answer (score 5):

In Apache, this is called a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

[The Apache wesbite has a configuration example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) I'm going to borrow, below.  Obviously, you'd want to replace the example DocumentRoots and ServerNames with your own, and make sure you have DNS setup properly.

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding  in httpd.conf or in apache.conf

here is the example..

```
    # Ensure that Apache listens on port 80

    Listen 80

    # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses

    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /www/example1

    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here

    </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This doesn't really appear to answer the OP's question; maybe with some reformatting and some clarification, your answer/solution could be clearer?

Comment: ...also, this seems to be contained entirely within the answer I posted ~5 hours earlier.  Not sure what, if anything, this adds to the question.

Comment: answer one is missing the conf file.. where we need to put this conf, so i have suggested.
"you can do this by adding in httpd.conf or in apache.conf"
for more clearification try below.

    <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /absolute/path/of/code/directory

    ServerName www.domainname.com

    # Other directives here

    </VirtualHost>

Answer (score -4):

First, you will have to setup LAMP on your VPS. LAMP stack is a group of open source software used to get web servers up and running. The acronym stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

Once LAMP is setup, you will have to setup Apache virtual hosts to host multiple websites on single IP address.There is no limit to the number of virtual hosts that can be added to a VPS. Here is good guide on how you can Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on CentOS 6 and Ubuntu 14.04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts